# How to check session exists or not in blade?

Tags: session, laravel-blade

Code:

```
@if (Auth::guest())
  <li><a href="/auth/login">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="/auth/register">Register</a></li>                    
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The Auth::guest() method returns true if the user is not logged in.
Use Auth::user() to return the logged in user, or false if the user is not logged in